# asp.net | webform 'website' (not application) | Umbraco CMS | additional content

Tags: asp.net, umbraco7

We have an old large asp.net webform 'website' (not application) website that needs a CMS adding to it. Can Umbraco be used for new additional content along side existing content pages

Comment: I need more detail to understand what you really want here. It also wouldn't hurt to give more detail on what your existing site is doing. Do you mean that you want to convert/integrate your existing webform site into an umbraco site? Or you are just looking at putting an umbraco site next to your website on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can create umbraco as service with service api and admin of umbraco,then in your existing content page you can load contents from umbraco CMS.
MORE https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/implementation/Rest-Api/